# How can I generate a multidimensional array (or tensor) quickly in Matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, tensor

I try to create a 3d-array with 3 indices `k=0,...,K-1, m'=0,...,M-1, m=0,...,M-1`. Can I generate such a 3d-array which the element at position `(k,m',m)` is `k/K+m'-m` in some quick way? My current approach is to use a 3-layer for-loop to calculate each element. It is a little clumsy and I believe there must be better way. So can anyone give me some inspiration? Grateful.
By the way another question. Can I generate a 3d-array from a matrix `A` and a vector `b`? I mean each element in `b` do some calculation with `A` so that we can derive a 3d-array? And how?

Comment: MATLAB uses 1-based indexing so the position (0,0,0) doesn't exist in an array.

Comment: That said, it sounds like you might want something like `[k,m1,m2] = ndgrid(0:(K-1), 0:(M-1), 0:(M-1)); result = k/K + m1 - m2;`

Comment: Thanks!@jodag You show me a powerful tool and help me a lot!:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create 3 vectors:

```
 k  of size [1 x K x 1] ,
 mp of size [M x 1 x 1] and
 m  of size [1 x 1 x M].
```

Using [implicit expansion](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) you can create the desired array:

```
K = 5;
M = 7;

k  = 0:K-1;
mp = (0:M-1).'
m  = reshape(0:M-1,1,1,[]);

result = k/K+mp-m;
```

Note that it is more efficient than `ndgrid` solution.

Comment: This is good. I tend to forget that MATLAB supports implicit expansion since 2016b!

Comment: Thank you! @rahnema1 I have tested you method and it works. It seems smart and I will refer to the official document to learn details. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help..!